# Autoload do composer não encontra classe 2

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Vi uma pergunta semelhante a minha, porém, tentei a solução proposta e não encontra a classe de modo nenhum. Já estou ficando desanimado em usar o autoloader do composer.

Importante: Meu ambiente é Windows (Server 2016) com IIS.
a estrutura fisica do meu diretório está assim:
[image: Local onde estao os arquivos]

meu composer.json (mesmo diretorio do index.php) está assim:

[image: composer.json]

Meu index está assim:

[image: index.php]

Minha classe Settings assim:

[image: classe Settings]

Já tentei diversas variações no use e no namespace. A resposta é sempre a mesma:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'EDAnT\Settings' not found in D:\WEB\WS\edant\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\WEB\WS\edant\index.php on line 9

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Apresente o codigo em forma de texto, nao de imagem, recomendo que leia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595

Comment: Observe a escrita  scr no autoload. src !=scr